# is there any more standard way to resume function from jQuery ajax call?

Tags: oop, jquery, import, visual-studio-2012, javascript-intellisense

I am trying to write a big project which involves of a lot of code. That's why I want to separate functionalities from different files.

the first file, dataJS, I make an AJAX call to get data from a JSON file. 
the second file, showJS I want to display the data obtained from the dataJS file.

When it comes to implementation, I realise that AJAX call takes longer time and even though I include dataJS and showJS in order, showJS will still get a null data

therefore I made a function called continueFromDataJS() in showJS file
and call continueFromDataJS() at the end of the AJAX *success* function.

I think it's a rather makedo solution. Is there any standard way to do it?

In addition, all intellisense in my Visual Studio is gone. Despite separate files, is there any way to make visual studio get intellisense from the dataJS?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us some code instead of just describing it?  How is the code being loaded, how/when is it being executed, what are the runtime values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I don't know how to add a follow up question
this is the code

for simplicity I rename some of the files and only take some part out of it. Hope that helps

code in html

code in dataJS.js

```
var planets = [];
var jsonData = null;

$(function () {

$.getJSON("Scripts/planetData.js", function (data) {
    //planets[0] = new planet("uranus", "career", 45, 700, 400, 0.1, 5, 3);
    jsonData = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.planets.length; i++) {

        var curPlanet = data.planets[i];

        planets[i] = new planet(curPlanet.graphic, i, curPlanet.field, curPlanet.planetInitialAngle, curPlanet.distanceFromStar, curPlanet.planetRadius, curPlanet.planetRevolvingSpeed, curPlanet.planetRotationSpeed, curPlanet.contents.length);

        $("#result").append("<p>" + curPlanet.graphic + " " + curPlanet.field + " " + curPlanet.planetInitialAngle + " " + curPlanet.distanceFromStar + " " + curPlanet.planetRadius + " " + curPlanet.planetRevolvingSpeed + " " + curPlanet.planetRotationSpeed + " " + curPlanet.contents.length + "</p>");

    }


    callDisplayScript(); //**continue from showJS.js file is that the way to do this?**

    });

});
// more functions below in dataJS.js
```

showJS.js

```
function callDisplayScript() { **// this is the ugly part. What's the proper way to do it?**
    $("#display #close").click(function () {
        $("#display").fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $article = $("#display article");
    $article.empty();
    var data = jsonData.planets[pID].contents; // **this line won't get jsonData if it's out this curly brace.**

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $article.append(data[i].title);
        $article.append(data[i].content);
    }

    $("#display").fadeIn('slow');
};
```

don't forget to answer my intellisense question. I want in datajs.js automatically hint planets and jsonData declared in datajs.js
is it possible?